# React Input onChange not firing at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been searching around and trying to find a solution that I don't understand why it's not working. No matter what I try it's not firing, and it doesn't matter where the input is (I placed an input in a different component and it wasn't firing there either). I even tried placing it outside of the component form with a console log and it still wasn't firing.

One other point I'm not using the create-react this is a webpack boilerplate. I don't think this is in connection with this (heck I'll try a test but that'll take a bit) but it's something just to mention.

I've even tried an onClick to test the function, and the function fires.

I've tried (this includes all of the thing along with the actual component):

```
<input type="text" id="email2" name="email2" onChange={(evt) => {
          console.log(evt); // eslint-disable-line
        }} value="asdf" />

<input type="text" className="aic-m-input-field__input" id="email" name="email" onChange={(evt) => this.handleOnChange(evt)} value={this.state.email} />

<input type="text" className="aic-m-input-field__input" id="email" name="email" onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.email} />

<input type="text" className="aic-m-input-field__input" id="email" name="email" onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.email} />
```

This is my contact-form component. It's a bit bare since I'm working on getting the functions to read

```
import React, { Component, state, setState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// import Alerts from '../components/Alerts/Alerts';

class ContactForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'ss',
      email: 'aa',
      subject: 'dd',
      message: 'dd'
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
  }

  _checkEmail(email) {
    const emailReg = /^[A-Za-z0-9!#$^&*|\-_+=~`?"]*([A-Za-z0-9!#$^&*|\-_+=~`?"]\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$^&*|\-_+=~`?"]+)*(\.{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9!#$^&*|\-_+=~`?"]@[A-Za-z0-9!#$^&*|\-_+=]{1,60})(\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$^&*|\-_+=~`?"]{2,60})*$/;
    return emailReg.test(email)
  }

  _checkSubject(subject) {
    return /^[A-z\s\w]{20}$/.test(subject)
  }

  _checkMessage(message) {
    return /REGEX/.test(message)
  }

  _checkForm(form) {
    if (!this._checkEmail(form[0].value)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!this._checkSubject(form[1].value)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!this._checkMessage(form[2].value)) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  _sendInputs(inputs) {
    console.log(inputs[0].value); // eslint-disable-line
  }

  handleOnChange(target) {
    const {name, value} = target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    // console.log(e); // eslint-disable-line
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputs = e.target;
    if (this._checkForm(inputs)) {
      this._sendInputs(inputs);
    }
    else {
      alert('no');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="bt-contact__form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="ail-grid__row aiu-spacing--m-bottom32">
          <div className="ail-grid__col--6">
            <section className="aic-m-input-field">
              <label className="aic-m-input-field--bordered aic-m-input-field__input-container">
                <span className="aic-m-input-field__label">Email</span> 
                <input type="text" className="aic-m-input-field__input" id="email" name="email" onChange={(evt) => this.handleOnChange(evt)} value={this.state.email} />
              </label>
            </section>
          </div>
          <div className="ail-grid__col--6">
            <section className="aic-m-input-field">
              <label className="aic-m-input-field--bordered aic-m-input-field__input-container">
                <span className="aic-m-input-field__label">Subject</span> 
                <input type="text" className="aic-m-input-field__input" onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.subject} />
              </label>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="ail-grid__row">
          <div className="ail-grid__col--12">
            <div className="aic-m-input-field aic-m-input-field--textarea">
              <label className="aic-m-input-field__textarea-container aic-m-input-field--bordered">
                <span className="aic-m-input-field__label">Label</span>
                <textarea className="aic-m-input-field__textarea" rows="2" data-min-rows="3" onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.message}></textarea>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div className="ail-grid__row">
          <div className="ail-grid__col--6">
            <button className="aic-a-button aic-a-button--secondary aic-a-button--default"><span className="aic-a-button__label">Nevermind</span></button>
          </div>
          <div className="ail-grid__col--6">
            <input type="submit" className="aiu-float--right aic-a-button aic-a-button--primary aic-a-button--default" role="submit" value="send message" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: Your code works fine - cannot reproduce. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lbbeay?file=src/ContactForm.js

Comment: @RandyCasburn Dang. I added a console log to what you did and it was firing ... The only thing I can think of is because this isn't a "create-react" app.

Comment: The `onChange` is called just fine, however your inputs don't all have a `name` so the state doesn't update like you expect. Also, you're passing the event, not the target, so you need `const {name, value} = event.target;` (you also definitely need to bind, I use `onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}` Blitz that actually works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ojeqxy?file=src/ContactForm.js

Comment: @ChrisG I tried that. Still didn't work. The code above the component is all of the ways I tried that.

Comment: I've updated the blitz to show minimal code to implement this.

Comment: @ChrisG Dang. Yeah it still doesn't work in the app. So it's not actually the onChange then. Ehh. I'm in the process of porting what i have to the create-react-app framework. Thanks for the Blitz though

Comment: Are you saying despite using my code exactly, your app's `onChange` isn't firing? But no error message at all? I don't think porting this will fix it.

Comment: @ChrisG probably not, but I don't know what else to do since an onClick will fire just fine. We'll see.

Comment: @ChrisG Again thanks for the blitzes I did figure out that the problem is in a different component that needs work but also has an issue. Still don't know why the onChange broke because of that component, but at least I've narrowed down the what.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1516352/alex Did you ever figure out what was going on? I am having the exact same problem and can't find an answer anywhere...